# Regression Spline basis functions

Tags: regression, splines, basis-function

I'm reading this book - [Generalized Additive Models](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Generalized-Additive-Models-Introduction-Simon-N-Wood/1584884746) by Simon Wood. On page 124, he defines basis for regression spline as (language is R)

```
# R(x,z) for cubic spline on [0,1], where z is knot and x is where we evalulate the basis
rk<-function(x,z){ 
((z-0.5)^2-1/12)*((x-0.5)^2-1/12)/4- ((abs(x-z)-0.5)^4-(abs(x-z)-0.5)^2/2+7/240)/24
}

# set up model matrix for cubic penalized regression spline
spl.X<-function(x,xk)
{ q<-length(xk)+2 # number of parameters
n<-length(x) # number of data
X<-matrix(1,n,q) # initialized model matrix
X[,2]<-x # set second column to x
X[,3:q]<-outer(x,xk,FUN=rk) # and remaining to R(x,xk)
X
}

xk=1:4/5 # choose some knots (0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8)
(X=spl.X(x,xk)) # generate model matrix
```

The author points to page 37 of book *Smoothing Spline ANOVA Models by Gu* for more details. I dont have this other book nor can I make sense of the basis function by myself. I am familiar with truncated power basis and BSpline representation but this seems very different.
Could someone please give me some pointers to understand the above basis function.